# File Upload from specified absolute path to server

Tags: java, file-upload

I want to upload file from a user provided absolute path on local machine to server.

For ex: If user inputs the following path:

```
 C:/abc/pqr/document.txt
```

then how can I upload "document.txt" from local to a folder on server

I tried this and it works on local to local, but my use case is for local to server. Is there a way to do so.

Comment: Are you trying to say `FTP` upload?

Comment: A lot of ways to upload a file exist.

Comment: @RomanC Can you tell me some helpful links for the same

Answer (score -1):

https://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-file-upload-example/

This tutorial is what you are looking for, it shows how to send a file from a jsp page to a Struts2 action.

The jsp can get the file from the local machine and the action is run on the server side, so the file will be there.

Comment: May be this link is helpful but without proper description it's useless and doesn't qualify for the answer.